# CSS text background hover effect behaving strangely on mouseout

Tags: css, css-animations, linear-gradients

I've implemented a hover effect on a h1 element (see code and pen below), but the effect is behaving strangely on mouse out and sort of flickering before going back to it's original state.

Any ideas how to make it transition back to it's original color as smoothly as it fades in on hover?

Thanks in advance.

https://codepen.io/lobodemon/pen/YOXKNJ

```css
h1 {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

h1:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  color:transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Gradient {
    0%, 100% {
        background-position: 0 50%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes Gradient {
    0%, 100% {
        background-position: 0 50%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%
    }
}

@keyframes Gradient {
    0%, 100% {
        background-position: 0 50%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>The Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to combine an animation with transtion which will not work like you expect. By adding a transtion you will not make the animation go smooth. In other words, you cannot add transtion to animation.

Since you made the duration of the animation to be `15s` on hover, I don't think the infinite is needed in this case because no one will keep hovering more than `15s`, so you can change this into a transition and it will be smooth.

I have added the black color to the gradient to have our initial state then with a transition we can do half the initial animation and at the end you will have a `7s` duration which is somehow enough for a hover effect:

```css
h1 {
  transition: 7s;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB,#000);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  color:transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

h1:hover {
  background-position: 100% 50%;
  
}
```

```html
<h1>The Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are working with transition, you need to set initial state of element properties that you are going to change.

```
h1 {
  background: black;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

I also found intresting example with same effect as yours.
https://codepen.io/anthony-liddle/pen/uFoxA

Comment: am not sure how this is answering the question and why it get 2 upvotes?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - although in the example you have provided, it seems to just be moving the background on hover, rather than adding/removing it. Also setting the initial values on the h1 didn't seem to have any effect :(