# css animation - mouse out smoothly

Tags: html, css, loops, animation, transform

Hello everyone i need help with my animation , i created a button moving right and left in loop and i have problem with mouse out from button. It's not smooth after taking mouse out it jump to start position.

```css
.hover {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: rgba(33, 150, 243, 1);
  transition: all .6s linear;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 50px;
  border: none;
}

.hover:hover {
  animation: pulse .6s infinite alternate;
  transition: all .6s linear;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(10px)
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="hover">Move Right And left</button>
</div>
```

Any idea what im doing wrong here?

Thanks :)

Comment: When it comes to animation you cannot avoid this

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51968018/css-text-background-hover-effect-behaving-strangely-on-mouseout/51969256#51969256

Comment: ok so the answer is simple , i cannot use transition with animation right?

Comment: yes, it doesn't make sense to add transition to an animation, so it won't work like you imagine

Comment: "so it won't work like you imagine " sadly :( , but thanks for answers.

Comment: Try using javascript to add the animation that you want as a class, on mouseenter.
On mouseleave remove the class, and it should transition back. It is avoidable imho.

Comment: @JudeDesir it will be exactly the same as it is now

Answer (score 1):

If a Javascript solution is acceptable, you might use [Web Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API) instead of CSS animations.
For some browsers you'll probably need a [Polyfill](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js).

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");

var a = btn.animate(
  [
    {transform: 'translateX(0px)'},
    {transform: 'translateX(10px)'},
    {transform: 'translateX(0px)'}
  ],
  1200
);

a.pause();

btn.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  btn.classList.add('hover');
  a.play();
});

btn.addEventListener('mouseout', () => btn.classList.remove('hover'));

a.addEventListener(
  'finish',
  () => {
    if (btn.classList.contains('hover'))
      a.play();
  }
);
```

```css
button {
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(33, 150, 243, 1);
}
```

```html
<!-- Polyfill -->
<script src="https://web-animations.github.io/web-animations-demos/components/web-animations-js/web-animations.min.js"></script>

<button>Move Right And left</button>
```